# How to wrap particles around a mesh?

Tags: modeling, particles

I'm trying to create an instant noodle thingy. This is what I have done so far. Is there a way to wrap those noodles dangling on the sides around the mesh?
Here is the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QOCqyj6Q-79jyTjYATt7qqsp_691jpEr/view?usp=sharing [image]

Comment: this might help，https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WAxMI1QJMQ&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=9

Comment: you could lower down the density on the sides with a vertex group but I don't understand why it doesn't work